# css multiple column and row article

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have created a section with multiple article but it doesn't work as expected. I want a multiple column (3 max) with multiple row.
 
But when I launch my script it doesn't do what I expected, when I have 3 article in the first row I have only one in the secound line (3 expected).
[It does this (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BlP09.png)
[But I expect this (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M73ov.png)

Code:

```css
.lesarticles {
  max-width: 1180px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

article {
  border: 1px solid #52535C;
  margin: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 1%;
  list-style: none;
  width: 130px;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

article p {
  text-align: left;
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
}

article img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="lesarticles">
  <article>
    <img src="img/img.png">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p>
  </article>

  <article>
    <img src="img/img2.png">
    <h2>Title 2</h2>
    <p>Ut rutrum nulla ex, id vulputate libero dignissim eget. Sed non tellus posuere, porttitor metus nec, faucibus nulla. Duis ut nunc viverra, tristique erat ut, ultricies leo. Pellentesque non tristique metus. Integer faucibus ornare diam at ornare.
      Etiam ut nisl quis velit bibendum mattis quis at nulla.</p>
  </article>

  <article>
    <img src="img/img3.png">
    <h2>Title 3</h2>
    <p>Nulla facilisi. Suspendisse pretium venenatis mauris, sed molestie tortor tempor vitae. Morbi semper mi id semper finibus.</p>
  </article>

  <article>
    <img src="img/img4.png">
    <h2>Title 4</h2>
    <p>Curabitur vel orci orci. Nulla nec suscipit elit, id auctor elit. Fusce hendrerit dolor eget nibh aliquet luctus. Fusce ut tempor nulla, eget cursus libero. Maecenas lobortis accumsan ipsum, eu porta enim elementum nec.</p>
  </article>

  <article>
    <img src="img/img5.png">
    <h2>Title 5</h2>
    <p>Curabitur vel orci orci. Nulla nec suscipit elit, id auctor elit. Fusce hendrerit dolor eget nibh aliquet luctus. Fusce ut tempor nulla, eget cursus libero. Maecenas lobortis accumsan ipsum, eu porta enim elementum nec.</p>
  </article>

  <article>
    <img src="img/img6.png">
    <h2>Title6</h2>
    <p>Curabitur vel orci orci. Nulla nec suscipit elit, id auctor elit. Fusce hendrerit dolor eget nibh aliquet luctus. Fusce ut tempor nulla, eget cursus libero. Maecenas lobortis accumsan ipsum, eu porta enim elementum nec.</p>
  </article>
</div>
```

Can you help me please ?

Comment: You need them to be same height, or at least set a wrapper that is the same height for them to align straight. Preferable solve it with just flex, then you dont have to set any height afaik https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to clear the float of every first element of the row using `clear:left` with the help of `nth-child` pseudo class like

```
article:nth-child(3n+1) {
  clear: left;
}
```

It will target the 1<sup>st</sup>, 4<sup>th</sup>, 7<sup>th</sup>... `article` to apply `clear:left`

***Stack Snippet***

```css
.lesarticles {
  max-width: 1180px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

article {
  border: 1px solid #52535C;
  margin: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 1%;
  list-style: none;
  width: 130px;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

article p {
  text-align: left;
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
}

article img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

article:nth-child(3n+1) {
  clear: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="lesarticles">
  <article>
    <img src="img/img.png">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p>
  </article>

  <article>
    <img src="img/img2.png">
    <h2>Title 2</h2>
    <p>Ut rutrum nulla ex, id vulputate libero dignissim eget. Sed non tellus posuere, porttitor metus nec, faucibus nulla. Duis ut nunc viverra, tristique erat ut, ultricies leo. Pellentesque non tristique metus. Integer faucibus ornare diam at ornare.
      Etiam ut nisl quis velit bibendum mattis quis at nulla.</p>
  </article>

  <article>
    <img src="img/img3.png">
    <h2>Title 3</h2>
    <p>Nulla facilisi. Suspendisse pretium venenatis mauris, sed molestie tortor tempor vitae. Morbi semper mi id semper finibus.</p>
  </article>

  <article>
    <img src="img/img4.png">
    <h2>Title 4</h2>
    <p>Curabitur vel orci orci. Nulla nec suscipit elit, id auctor elit. Fusce hendrerit dolor eget nibh aliquet luctus. Fusce ut tempor nulla, eget cursus libero. Maecenas lobortis accumsan ipsum, eu porta enim elementum nec.</p>
  </article>

  <article>
    <img src="img/img5.png">
    <h2>Title 5</h2>
    <p>Curabitur vel orci orci. Nulla nec suscipit elit, id auctor elit. Fusce hendrerit dolor eget nibh aliquet luctus. Fusce ut tempor nulla, eget cursus libero. Maecenas lobortis accumsan ipsum, eu porta enim elementum nec.</p>
  </article>

  <article>
    <img src="img/img6.png">
    <h2>Title6</h2>
    <p>Curabitur vel orci orci. Nulla nec suscipit elit, id auctor elit. Fusce hendrerit dolor eget nibh aliquet luctus. Fusce ut tempor nulla, eget cursus libero. Maecenas lobortis accumsan ipsum, eu porta enim elementum nec.</p>
  </article>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you but it doesn't work if i have only 2 articles in a row because i want to do it responsive. I keep your idea and i will change with a media query
Thanks

Comment: @PiR you will need to  use the `article:nth-child(2n+1)` in case you want to show to show 2 items per row...you can use media query for this

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is what you were looking for. Happy to explain or help in a better solution if needed.

```css
.lesarticles {
  max-width: 1180px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

article {
  border: 1px solid #52535C;
  margin: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 1%;
  list-style: none;
  width: 130px;
  display: inline-grid;
  overflow: hidden;
}

article p {
  text-align: left;
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
}

article img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.article-row {display: block;}
```

```html
<div class="lesarticles">
<div class="article-row">
  <article>
    <img src="img/img.png">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p>
  </article>

  <article>
    <img src="img/img2.png">
    <h2>Title 2</h2>
    <p>Ut rutrum nulla ex, id vulputate libero dignissim eget. Sed non tellus posuere, porttitor metus nec, faucibus nulla. Duis ut nunc viverra, tristique erat ut, ultricies leo. Pellentesque non tristique metus. Integer faucibus ornare diam at ornare.
      Etiam ut nisl quis velit bibendum mattis quis at nulla.</p>
  </article>

  <article>
    <img src="img/img3.png">
    <h2>Title 3</h2>
    <p>Nulla facilisi. Suspendisse pretium venenatis mauris, sed molestie tortor tempor vitae. Morbi semper mi id semper finibus.</p>
  </article>
</div>
  
<div class="article-row">
  <article>
    <img src="img/img4.png">
    <h2>Title 4</h2>
    <p>Curabitur vel orci orci. Nulla nec suscipit elit, id auctor elit. Fusce hendrerit dolor eget nibh aliquet luctus. Fusce ut tempor nulla, eget cursus libero. Maecenas lobortis accumsan ipsum, eu porta enim elementum nec.</p>
  </article>

  <article>
    <img src="img/img5.png">
    <h2>Title 5</h2>
    <p>Curabitur vel orci orci. Nulla nec suscipit elit, id auctor elit. Fusce hendrerit dolor eget nibh aliquet luctus. Fusce ut tempor nulla, eget cursus libero. Maecenas lobortis accumsan ipsum, eu porta enim elementum nec.</p>
  </article>

  <article>
    <img src="img/img6.png">
    <h2>Title6</h2>
    <p>Curabitur vel orci orci. Nulla nec suscipit elit, id auctor elit. Fusce hendrerit dolor eget nibh aliquet luctus. Fusce ut tempor nulla, eget cursus libero. Maecenas lobortis accumsan ipsum, eu porta enim elementum nec.</p>
  </article>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `clear:left` to every third article after the initial four. You can do this by using `:nth-child(3n+1)`

```css
.lesarticles {
  max-width: 1180px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

article {
  border: 1px solid #52535C;
  margin: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 1%;
  list-style: none;
  width: 130px;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

article p {
  text-align: left;
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
}

article img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
article:nth-child(3n+1){
clear:left;
}
```

```html
<div class="lesarticles">
  <article>
    <img src="img/img.png">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p>
  </article>

  <article>
    <img src="img/img2.png">
    <h2>Title 2</h2>
    <p>Ut rutrum nulla ex, id vulputate libero dignissim eget. Sed non tellus posuere, porttitor metus nec, faucibus nulla. Duis ut nunc viverra, tristique erat ut, ultricies leo. Pellentesque non tristique metus. Integer faucibus ornare diam at ornare.
      Etiam ut nisl quis velit bibendum mattis quis at nulla.</p>
  </article>

  <article>
    <img src="img/img3.png">
    <h2>Title 3</h2>
    <p>Nulla facilisi. Suspendisse pretium venenatis mauris, sed molestie tortor tempor vitae. Morbi semper mi id semper finibus.</p>
  </article>

  <article>
    <img src="img/img4.png">
    <h2>Title 4</h2>
    <p>Curabitur vel orci orci. Nulla nec suscipit elit, id auctor elit. Fusce hendrerit dolor eget nibh aliquet luctus. Fusce ut tempor nulla, eget cursus libero. Maecenas lobortis accumsan ipsum, eu porta enim elementum nec.</p>
  </article>

  <article>
    <img src="img/img5.png">
    <h2>Title 5</h2>
    <p>Curabitur vel orci orci. Nulla nec suscipit elit, id auctor elit. Fusce hendrerit dolor eget nibh aliquet luctus. Fusce ut tempor nulla, eget cursus libero. Maecenas lobortis accumsan ipsum, eu porta enim elementum nec.</p>
  </article>

  <article>
    <img src="img/img6.png">
    <h2>Title6</h2>
    <p>Curabitur vel orci orci. Nulla nec suscipit elit, id auctor elit. Fusce hendrerit dolor eget nibh aliquet luctus. </p>
  </article>
    <article>
    <img src="img/img2.png">
    <h2>Title 7</h2>
    <p>Ut rutrum nulla ex, id vulputate libero dignissim eget. Sed non tellus posuere, porttitor metus nec, faucibus nulla. Duis ut nunc viverra, tristique erat ut, ultricies leo. Pellentesque non tristique metus. Integer faucibus ornare diam at ornare.
      Etiam ut nisl quis velit bibendum mattis quis at nulla.</p>
  </article>

  <article>
    <img src="img/img3.png">
    <h2>Title 8</h2>
    <p>Nulla facilisi. Suspendisse pretium venenatis mauris, sed molestie tortor tempor vitae. Morbi semper mi id semper finibus.</p>
  </article>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, I posted it just a few seconds after. Didn't realize it

Answer (score -1):

Here is a modified version, you just have to set the right height:

Possible Solution:

```
`https://jsfiddle.net/0eyxswcj/13/`
```

Comment: Please do not post your answers as links to other locations.